# Showing error in function pointer code

Tags: c, function, pointers

I have written a code that uses function pointers to compare strings. But, it is showing me errors and I don't know how to correct them. Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void sports_no_bieber(char *);  
void science_sports(char *);
void theater_no_guys(char *);
int find(int(*match)(char*)); 
int NUM_ADS=4;
char *ADS[]={
                "Sarah:girls, sports, science",
                "William: sports, TV, dining",
                "Matt: art, movies, theater",
                "Luis: books, theater, guys",
                "Josh: sports, movies, theater"
            };
int main()
{
printf("Bachelorette Amanda needs your help! He wants someone who likes sports but not  bieber.\n");
find(sports_no_bieber);
printf("Bachelorette Susan needs your help! She wants someone who likes science and sports. (And girls).\n");
find(science_sports);
printf("Bachelorette Emily needs your help! She wants someone who likes theater but not guys.\n");
find(theater_no_guys);
return 0;
}



int find(int(*match)(char* ))
{
        int i;
      puts("Search results\n");
puts("--------------------");
for(i=0;i<NUM_ADS;i++)
{
    if(match(ADS[i]))
        printf("%s\n",ADS[i];
}
puts("--------------------");
return i;
}

int sports_no_bieber(char * s)
{
return  (strstr(s, "sports")) && (!strstr (s,"bieber") );
}

int science_sports(char * s)
{
return  (strstr(s, "science")) && (strstr (s,"sports" ));
}

int theater_no_guys(char * s)
{
return (strstr(s, "theater"))&&(!strstr(s,"guys"));
}
```

and the error it shows is

```
E:\ComputerPrograming\FunctionPointer.c: In function `int main()':
E:\ComputerPrograming\FunctionPointer.c:18: passing `void (*)(char *)' as argument 1 of `find(int (*)(char *))'
E:\ComputerPrograming\FunctionPointer.c:20: passing `void (*)(char *)' as argument 1 of `find(int (*)(char *))'
E:\ComputerPrograming\FunctionPointer.c:22: passing `void (*)(char *)' as argument 1 of `find(int (*)(char *))'
E:\ComputerPrograming\FunctionPointer.c: In function `int find(int (*)(char *))':
E:\ComputerPrograming\FunctionPointer.c:36: parse error before `;'
E:\ComputerPrograming\FunctionPointer.c:40: confused by earlier errors, bailing out
```

I even tried making the find function into an int function...but that didn't make any difference. What exactly does the error mean?

Comment: Your function prototypes don't match your function definitions...

Answer (score 4):

These function declarations:

```
void sports_no_bieber(char *);  
void science_sports(char *);
void theater_no_guys(char *);
```

do not match the signature of the function pointer required by `find()` or their definitions. Change to:

```
int sports_no_bieber(char *);  
int science_sports(char *);
int theater_no_guys(char *);
```

Note that `NUM_ADS` does not equal the number of elements in the `ADS` array: it is one less. To avoid having to ensure `NUM_ADS` and `ADS` are correct terminate the `NUM_ADS` array with a `NULL` pointer and use it as the loop terminating condition (and discard `NUM_ADS`):

```
const char *ADS[] =
{
    "Sarah:girls, sports, science",
    "William: sports, TV, dining",
    "Matt: art, movies, theater",
    "Luis: books, theater, guys",
    "Josh: sports, movies, theater",
    NULL
};

for(int i=0; ADS[i]; i++)
{
```

Suggest making all function argument types to be `const char* const` instead of `char*` as none of the functions modify the content or re-assign the pointer.

Comment: Ah. Thanks for pointing that out. That was fairly stupid of me.

Answer (score 1):

You have two types of errors, first is a mismatch between the prototypes and the functions themselves.

```
void sports_no_bieber(char *);  
 ^          ^            ^
 |          |            |
these much mach        the types here must 
  exactly               match
 |          |            |
 v          v            v
int sports_no_bieber(char * s)
```

So you need the name and return types to be the same, just as you do with the parameter types. In your case the return types do not match for `sports_no_bieber()`, `science_sports()`, and `theater_no_guys()`.

One way to avoid this issue is to move the function definition above the point they are used, that removes the need for prototypes and eliminates the chance of mistyping them... of course you could also just copy and paste to avoid silly mistakes like this.

The other error you have is in your `find()` function you missed a parenthesis:

```
printf("%s\n",ADS[i];   // <-- missed the close )
```